# How to rearrange from lowest to highest value in Python?

Tags: python, ranking

I am trying to rearrange a set of numbers, however, I am trying to have the lowest number have the highest rank

My input is
list=[312198.0, 306400.0, 270345.0, 367979.0, 375502.0]

and my desired output is
rank=[3,4,5,2,1]

My code is:

```
list=[312198.0, 306400.0, 270345.0, 367979.0, 375502.0]
seq = sorted(x)
index = [seq.index(v) for v in x]
print(index)
```

My current output is [2, 1, 0, 3, 4]

Comment: `index = [seq.index(v) + 1 for v in x]` ?

Comment: `[seq.index(v) + 1 for v in x]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the indexes in decreasing order of values and assign the rank value at the sorted index position:

```
L=[312198.0, 306400.0, 270345.0, 367979.0, 375502.0]

ranks = list(range(len(L)))
for r,i in enumerate(sorted(ranks,key=lambda i:L[i],reverse=True),1):
    ranks[i]=r

print(ranks)
[3, 4, 5, 2, 1]
```

You could also do this more concisely (but less efficiently) using a list comprehension wherein you count the number of items that are greater than each value:

```
ranks = [1+sum(item > value for item in L) for value in L]
```

*The first solution is O(NlogN) and the second one is O(N^2)*

*Also note that the 1st solution will give different ranks to equal values but the second one will give them the same rank*

Answer (score 1):

You just have it actually,with a plus one while you are initializing the `index` array.

```
def answer():
    list = [312198.0, 306400.0, 270345.0, 367979.0, 375502.0]
    seq = sorted(list)
    index = [seq.index(v) + 1  for v in list]
    print(index)
```

Comment: and you have a compilation error on your code while sorting, i am assumin you are sorting the original array not an unknown variable called `x`

Comment: Indeed, I am sorting the original array, however, I've realized that I did ask the question the other way around. I need to sort it in such a manner, that the highest cost has value 1, and the lowest, has 5.

Comment: Don't use list as a variable name, it shadows (and causes reader confusion) the built in list